# Error while retrieving data from Firebase(The getter 'cover' was called on null.)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am trying to call data from `Firebase` but I found the below error, while start login for first time, and this is the below error:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building BlocBuilder<AppCubit, AppStates>(dirty, state: _BlocBuilderBaseState<AppCubit, AppStates>#b335d):
The getter 'cover' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: cover
```

and this is the below related code:

```
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(
                              '${userModel.cover}',
                            ),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
```

and this is the full code I have :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:mysocially/shared/cubit/cubit.dart';
import 'package:mysocially/shared/cubit/states.dart';
import 'package:mysocially/styles/icon_broken.dart';

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
      builder: (context, state) {
        var userModel = AppCubit.get(context).model;

        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 190.0,
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 140.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                          ),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(
                              '${userModel.cover}',
                            ),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 51.0,
                      backgroundColor:
                          Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        // radius: responsive.height * 0.025,
                        radius: 50.0,
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          '${userModel.image}',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5.0,
              ),
              Text(
                '${userModel.name}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
              ),
              Text(
                '${userModel.bio}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '100',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Posts',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '100',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Posts',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '62',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Photos',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '200',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Followers',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '600',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Followings',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: OutlinedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text('Add Photos'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                  OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Icon(
                      IconBroken.Edit,
                      size: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

cubit class which containes the business logic:

```
class AppCubit extends Cubit<AppStates> {
  AppCubit() : super(AppInitialState());

  static AppCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of(context);

  UserModel model;

  void getUserData() {
    emit(AppGetUserLoadingState());
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uId).get().then((value) {
      // print(value.data());
      model = UserModel.fromJson(value.data());
      emit(
        AppGetUserSuccessState(),
      );
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error.toString());
      emit(
        AppGetUserErrorState(
          error.toString(),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

The code works Fine when I make `hot reload` or restart the app but it gives this error first `Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.` and then show the data...

So How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using BLoC, you should get the user model from it like this:

`final userModel = state.model;`

and not like this:

`var userModel = AppCubit.get(context).model;`

Also, when you only need to get the state of the cubit (for widget building), use `BlocBuilder` and not a `BlocConsumer`.

Comment: I am getting the same error :( , and how about if I need to use the listener?

Comment: From what I see there, you do not need a listener since you are building the UI. It would help if you add what's going on inside AppCubit/AppStates.

Comment: am sorry but how about `The getter 'model' isn't defined for the type 'AppStates'` how can I handle this error I think I didn't make the right syntax

Comment: I have posted my cubit class please check :)

Comment: I see... You cannot access the model from Cubit like that, what you access inside BlocBuilder (or BlocConsumer) is the state. So you should store the model inside your state and only then you can get it in the UI. I would recommend checking the official Firestore tutorial in the documentation first, so you can see how BLoC communicates with Firestore and how the state is used: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirestoretodostutorial

Comment: thank for your support :), I'll check this